Is there way to have polymorphic behaviour for convertors from DTO to model?
I have endpoint which accepts BaseDto:
@JsonTypeInfo(...)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(...),
    ...
})
@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    value = "/path",
    produces = { "application/json" },
    consumes = { "application/json" }
)

 fun foo(@Valid @RequestBody dto:BaseDto ):ResponseEntity<?> {
   ...
}

Dto has inheritance hierarchy:
class Child1Dto : BaseDto { 
class Child2Dto : BaseDto { 
class Child3Dto : BaseDto { 
...

So in the controller I have Child1Dto or Child2Dto or Child3Dto
Also I have Model BaseModel
class Child1Model : BaseModel {
class Child2Model : BaseModel {
class Child3Model : BaseModel {

Now I have following code:
fun BaseDto.toModel(): BaseModel =
    when (this) {
        is Child1Dto -> Child1Model(/*no args*/)
        is Child2Dto  -> Child2Model(/*no args*/)
        is Child3Dto -> Child3Model(/*some args from dto*/)
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unknown dto type ${this::class}")
    }

I don't like this code because of

Dto knows about model
Switch doesn't look nice. In most cases I try to replace switch with polymorphism but I don't know how to do it here.

Is there better way to rewrite this code ?

How about using MapStruct, specifically SubclassMapping? You would have that in your Controller layer, outside of the Dto class. Admittedly, the way you specify subclass equivalences is no better than the switch.

@k314159 interesting idea. I would appreciate if you provide detailed answer

I might try, when I get some time, but I don't think such an answer would be great as it wouldn't use polymorphism as stated in your bullet point 2.

@k314159 But if there is no way for polymorphism - I will try to find the best way without polymorphism

You can check out @JsonSubTypes that allow polymorphic deserialization
So for example you can define a parent:
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "fooProperty", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildClassOne.class, name = "foo"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildClassTwo.class, name = "bar"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildClassThree.class, name = "baz")
}) public abstract class BaseDto { 
    public String fooProperty;
}

then based on the value of fooProperty, JSON will be deserialized into the coresponding child class

You are correct but conversion from json to Dto happens properly. My question is about converion from Dto to Model

add a new method toModel for decouple the DTO from the Model
abstract class BaseDto {
    abstract fun toModel(): BaseModel
}

and then implement the Method in Each Child Class
class Child1Dto : BaseDto() {
    override fun toModel(): BaseModel {
        return Child1Model()
    }
}

class Child2Dto : BaseDto() {
    override fun toModel(): BaseModel {
        return Child2Model()
    }
}

class Child3Dto : BaseDto() {
    override fun toModel(): BaseModel {
        return Child3Model(/* map necessary arguments here */)
    }
}



At this case Dto aware about model which is not a good practice

You can do that. You will have to have a switch or map somewhere, but it can be hidden from the controller.

You add a mapping layer that maps models to DTOs. There is an abstract mapper, and 3 concrete mapper classes. That way the DTOs are no longer aware of the models.
Create a centralized mapper, which exposes a single map function for the controller to use, and chooses the appropriate concrete mapper.

Centralized mapper:
object DtoMapperRegistry {
    private val mappers: Map<Class<out BaseDto>, DtoToModelMapper<out BaseDto, out BaseModel>> = mapOf(
        Child1Dto::class.java to Child1DtoMapper(),
        Child2Dto::class.java to Child2DtoMapper(),
        Child3Dto::class.java to Child3DtoMapper()
    )

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun <D : BaseDto, M : BaseModel> map(dto: D): M {
        val mapper = mappers[dto::class.java]
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("No mapper found for ${dto::class}")
        return (mapper as DtoToModelMapper<D, M>).map(dto)
    }
}

To use it you just need a single call:
val model = DtoMapperRegistry.map(dto)

